# How to make sure unique id will be generated?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign a unique Id to my button which is created dynamically this way

This is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

    var uniqueNumber = new Date().getTime();

            var $ordernow = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: 'button',
                name: 'btn1',
                class: 'ordernow btn btn-' + classstyle + '',
                value: 'Order Now',
                id : uniqueNumber,
                style: 'float:right'
            });

    }
```

But sometimes i observe that the id that is being genertaed is sometimes same (However this is not happening every time) as shown above

This is the HTML that is generated for the above

```
<div class="inner-intit">
   <input type="button" name="btn1" class="ordernow btn btn-success" value="Order Now" id="1412689973307" style="float:right">
   <input type="button" name="btn1" class="ordernow btn btn-success" value="Order Now" id="1412689973307" style="float:right">
</div>
```

Is there any solution  how to recitify this ??

Just for additional information this is how the UI looks for my screen

[image]

Comment: try `uniqueNumber + i`

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `i` instead of something like `getTime()`?

Comment: @Anton this seems to be the perfect solution thank you very much .

Comment: Avoid using IDs if you can. Use unique or indexed (`[n]`) `name` attributes for inputs and classes where possible instead.

Comment: @Anton Make it an answer.

Comment: @PreethiJain: anton posted his comment as answer. do mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a random string after the timestamp. With an alpha numeric string of 6 or more characters, plus the timestamp, the chance of overlap is incredibly unlikely.

However, you may rethink the approach you are taking. You probably don't need a front-end generated unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `i` and add it to `uniqueNumber`

```
id : uniqueNumber + i,
```